# Running Maven Spring project in eclipse using Web preview server

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, websphere

getting an error while running in web preview server in eclipse but the same projects runs fine in tomcat.

Error
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:75)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:110)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:216)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.loadListener(WebApp.java:2176)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0279E: Error occured while processing global listeners for the application {0}: {1}
java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] SRVE8052E: Logging ClassNotFoundException
org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [dispatcher]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]: Could not find required class - org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1497)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]: Could not find required class - org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:486)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]: Could not find required class - org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet
    ... 3 more

Comment: Here is the link how i installed the server in eclipse https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/websphere-application-server-v8-5-5-next-alpha-liberty-profile/

Answer (score 0):

this may cause by either

- There is no Spring jars in WEB-INF/lib

or

- You need to change WebSphere class load policy to PARENT LAST